# Let $A$ be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that $A$ and $A^5$ have the same null space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that $A$ and $A^5$ have the same null space.

This question came up when I was solving. And I'm not entirely sure on how to approach it, is it valid to just write $A^4(AX) = 0$ (assuming here that $X$ belongs to the null space of $A$), which would give $0$, meaning that $A$ and $A^5$ have the same null space?

Comment: No, this only means that the null space of $A$ is contained in the null space of $A^5$. You need to show the reverse inclusion as well.

Comment: Note: it's always true that $\operatorname{Nul}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{Nul}(A^5)$ for the reason you have given, but the reverse inclusion is not guaranteed in general. 

In fact, $\operatorname{Nul}(A^p) \subseteq \operatorname{Nul}(A^q)$ whenever $p \leq q$ by just observing that $A^q = A^{q-p} A^p$.

Comment: Oh yeah right. So what approach should I use to prove the statement? I cant think of anything unfortunately

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We clearly have $\ker A\subset \ker A^5\subset \ker A^8.$ Assume $v\in \ker A^8.$ Then by symmetry we have $$0=\langle A^8v,v\rangle =\langle A^4v,A^4v\rangle $$ Hence $A^4v=0,$ i.e. $v\in\ker A^4.$ Applying the same procedure twice we get $v\in \ker A.$ Therefore $\ker A^5\subset \ker A^8\subset \ker A.$

Comment: There was a misprint, now corrected.

Comment: This is a beautiful proof

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I just have 1 question, did we here use the fact the A is symmetric?

Comment: The symmetry has been used in the formula $\langle Av,w\rangle =\langle v, Aw\rangle$ Besides the conclusion does not hold without symmetry assumption.

Answer (score 6):

The key is that real symmetric matrices have a spanning set of eigenvectors (i.e. the set of its eigenvectors spans $\mathbb{R}^n$), thus assume the vectors $(\mathbf{v}_i)$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, where each $\mathbf{v}_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Then to show, that the nullspace of $A^5$ is included in the nullspace of $A$ we need to show

$$ A^5 \mathbf{v} = 0 \implies A\mathbf{v}=0$$

Note that we can write $\mathbf{v}$ uniquely as a linear combination of eigenvectors $(\mathbf{v}_i)$ as

$$ \mathbf{v} = \sum \alpha_i \mathbf{v}_i $$

But then

$$ A^5\mathbf{v} = \sum \lambda_i^5 \alpha_i \mathbf{v}_i = 0$$

Which implies

$$ \lambda_i^5 \alpha_i = 0 $$

Which in turn implies

$$ \lambda_i \alpha_i = 0$$

But this means the only non-zero coefficients $\alpha_i$ were paired with eigenvectors that have a $0$ eigenvalue, i.e. vectors in the nullspace of $A$. So $\mathbf{v}$ is a linear combination of vectors in the nullspace of $A$, hence $\mathbf{v}$ is in the nullspace of $A$, completing the proof.

Comment: For the last part of the proof, note simply that $A\mathbf{v} = \sum \lambda_i \alpha_i \mathbf{v}_i $, and each $\lambda_i \alpha_i $ is $0$ (since $\lambda_i^5 \alpha_i = 0$)
, thus $A\mathbf{v} = 0$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon, ah thank you for pointing this out!